# XSLT find first text node

Tags: xslt, select

I'm been given a piece of messy HTML, which I've cleaned with HTML tidy. I am trying to turn this into a version of DITA.

I want to get the first element with text in it, and turn it into a chapter title.

I've got a file (simplified):

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<p><img src="i.gif" alt="int.gif (792 bytes)" border="0" width="105" height="18" /> 
    <strong>
       <a class="c1" name="flag" id="flag">Flags</a>
     </strong>
 </p>
<!-- the elements between the first p and the actual text may vary. -->
<!--more -->
```

Or sometimes it is like this:

```
  <html><head></head>
    <body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody> <!-- sometimes this is missing !! -->
    <tr>
    <td class="c3" width="100%">
        <span class="c2">
            <a class="c1" name="Errors" id="errors">Error-Codes</a>   <strong>with troubleshooting</strong>
        </span>
     </td></tr></tbody></table>  <!--more --></body></html>
```

Or could potentially be something else.

I've tried these:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:element name="chapter">
        <xsl:element name="title">
            <!-- <xsl:value-of select="table[1]//td[1]"/> first td, but not p -->
            <!-- <xsl:value-of select="./p[1]//text()"/> first para
            <!-- <xsl:value-of select="table[1]//td()[1] or p[1]"/> invalid syntax -->
            <!-- <xsl:value-of select="text()[1]"/>  nothing -->
            <!-- <xsl:value-of select="//text()[1]"/> gets all text in document -->
        </xsl:element>
```

---

I've also tried

```
<!--  <xsl:value-of select=".//*[@class='c1'][1]"/> gets first instance of child node with class="c1" of every subnode, with are often many -->
```

---

By popular request ;-) this is what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE chapter SYSTEM "our.dtd">
<chapter template-version="01">
    <title>Flags</title>
<!-- blabbity blab -->
</chapter>
```

or

```
<chapter template-version="01">
    <title>Error codes with troubleshooting</title>
      <!-- I would also accept just "Error codes", 
           I could leave some billable work for later -->
<!-- blabbity blab -->
</chapter>
```

Comment: You forgot to include what result you expect, exactly. What's the correct output XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the first element with text in it, and turn it into a chapter title.

This is not quite as easy as it may sound. What is *"the first element with text in it"*, anyway?

In your first example, it would be this:

```
<a class="c1" name="flag" id="flag">Flags</a>
```

Easy enough. In your second example, by the same logic, it would be this:

```
<a class="c1" name="Errors" id="errors">Error-Codes</a>
```

But of course it's not that easy, because you actually want *this*:

```
<span class="c2">
    <a class="c1" name="Errors" id="errors">Error-Codes</a>   <strong>with troubleshooting</strong>
</span>
```

So what's the defining characteristic of the element that you want to use as your title?

I'll make an educated guess and define it as:

**The first non-inline element that does not contain other non-inline elements and has non-empty text.**

*"Non-inline" means all [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) as well as `<td>` and so on, which have technical differences to block-level elements that are irrelevant in this case.*

---

So using this definition with your first example gets us to:

```
<p><img src="i.gif" alt="int.gif (792 bytes)" border="0" width="105" height="18" /> 
    <strong>
       <a class="c1" name="flag" id="flag">Flags</a>
     </strong>
</p>
```

whose text value is still "Flags".

In your second example the element we would end up with:

```
<td class="c3" width="100%">
    <span class="c2">
        <a class="c1" name="Errors" id="errors">Error-Codes</a>   <strong>with troubleshooting</strong>
    </span>
</td>
```

whose text value would be "Error-Codes with troubleshooting".

Seems the definition works for the examples you gave.

---

XPath that matches all relevant "non-inline" elements could look like this:

```
//*[self::p|self::td|self::div|self::and-so-on]
```

Add more container element types as you need them.

When we include the condition that it should not contain other elements of the same type, we end up with:

```
//*[self::p|self::td|self::div|self::and-so-on][
    not(.//*[self::p|self::td|self::div|self::and-so-on])
]
```

Adding the condition that it must contain some text:

```
//*[self::p|self::td|self::div|self::and-so-on][
    not(.//*[self::p|self::td|self::div|self::and-so-on])
    and normalize-space() != ''
]
```

...and that of all those fulfilling this condition throughout the document, we only need the first one:

```
(//*[self::p|self::td|self::div|self::and-so-on][
    not(.//*[self::p|self::td|self::div|self::and-so-on])
    and normalize-space() != ''
])[1]
```

and of that first one, we want the normalized text value:

```
normalize-space(
    (//*[self::p|self::td|self::div|self::and-so-on][
       not(.//*[self::p|self::td|self::div|self::and-so-on])
        and normalize-space() != ''
    ])[1]
)
```

All of this in XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
  <title>
    <xsl:value-of select="
        normalize-space(
            (//*[self::p|self::td|self::div|self::and-so-on][
               not(.//*[self::p|self::td|self::div|self::and-so-on])
                and normalize-space() != ''
            ])[1]
        )
    " />
  </title>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Um. thank you. That actually seems to work. I can add to it, and put in every element of HTML that supports text content.  
If I can impose further on your time and goodwill, would it be possible to explain that select statement to me?

Comment: I thought I did, in the lines above? Did you read them? What's unclear about it, exactly?

Comment: Hm. Okay. I am not sure I understand this "axis" thing. 

"An axis defines a node-set relative to the current node." (http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp). And `self` selects the current node. The "." also selects the current node. 

`self` _axis_ Contains the context node itself. The self axis can be abbreviated with a single period (.). The expressions `self::*` and . are equivalent. (http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xslt/ch03_02.htm)

Comment: So, therefore `//*` selects all nodes, and `[self::p]` limits it to p nodes below the current node in the tree. This sounds like the same thing as `.//p`. Or so it sounds.

But `<xsl:value-of select=".//p[1]"/>` returns the value of every initial p element in its parent. 
And `<xsl:value-of select="( //*[self::p])[1]" />` returns the content of only the very first p element the parser meets under the current node. Why is that?

If the explanation is too long, I could raise this as another question, but if so, what exactly should the question be?

Comment: I'll raise another question. Very impressive piece of XSLT there.

Comment: Well, I'll try to explain some of it. But for an XPath primer the comments of SO are not the right medium. And of course, XPath tutorials have been written, so there is enough reading material available already.

Comment: `//*` selects all *element* nodes (there are other types of nodes, but the `*` does not select them) and `[self::p]` filters them down to those that are *themselves* `<p>`. Also, `.` and `self::` are not at all the same thing. The `.` sets a reference point for navigation. It anchors the expression (or sub-expression) at the context element. All navigation is done along axes. `./*` is an abbreviation of `./child::*` and could be read as *"with reference to the current node (`.`), select (`/`) all child elements (`*`)"*.

Comment: Whereas `./child::*[self::p]` could be read as *"with reference to the current node, select all child elements where (`[`) each of them is itself a `<p>`"*. Of course, since the current node and `child::` are the defaults for XPath navigation, `*[self::p]` is the same thing. If you only want `<p>`, simply using `p` would be even shorter. But to express "any child element as long as it is `<div>`, `<p>`, `<td>`, and so on, `*[self:div|self::p|self::td]` becomes a viable option.

Comment: And while `.` sets a reference point for navigation, axes set the scope of available nodes to navigate *to*. `child::` sets the scope to child nodes. `parent::` to the parent node. `ancestor::` to all parent nodes. And so on. `self::` sets the scope of available nodes to the current node only. And `self::p` only ever can select a node when the current node is, in fact, itself a `<p>`. Otherwise it selects nothing, i.e. an empty set, which in a predicate will be interpreted as `false`. `*[self::p]` works that way.

Comment: I'm sorry to be very slow in understanding you, Tomalak, but I really am not sure what you mean by "_itself_ a `<p>`". Surely a descendant is either a <p> or it isn't. What does "_itself_ a <p>" mean here? 
I've asked this now, as a separate question, which seems like the best thing. Thanks for the input so far.

Comment: Actually, although your code solves my immediate problem, I would be interested to see if anyone has an answer to 
"How can I select the first text node in a document?"

Comment: In `*[self::p]` the `self::p` applies to whatever the `*` selected. It applies to *itself*. There is descendant involved. Assume `*` would select 4 elements, `<div>`, `<p>` and `<b>` and another `<p>`. Now with `*[self::p]` that initial selection would be filtered down to those nodes that are *themselves* `<p>`, i.e., after the filter you have 2 nodes remaining.

Comment: *"How can I select the first text node in a document?"* - `(//text())[1]`. *"How can I select the first text node in a document that has more than whitespace?"* - `(//text()[normalize-space() != ''])[1]`.

Comment: I think we should leave it at that. This has gotten out of hand already. Comments are the wrong place to do this, and, as I said, XPath tutorials have been written. Read and experiment, you will get the hang of it.

Comment: Thanks, what you you recommend? 
I've looked at [W3Schools] (http://www.w3schools.com/xsl)
Microsoft [XSLT concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754602(v=vs.85).aspx)
and a few other things from [O'Reilly](http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/#a_template_rule)(http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100087.do)
(http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xslt/ch03_02.htm)
None of these mentioned that it was valid syntax to put round brackets _before_ square brackets, and I admit I never thought of it. `(path)[1]` - should I have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124232/discussion-between-rawtext-and-tomalak).

Comment: @rawtext No, let's not. ;) 1-on-1 interactive lessons are way out of scope for StackOverflow. The questions you have are all perfectly valid questions that fit the site's Q&A format (except the ones that are about learning resource recommendations, they are off topic, you'll have to find resources yourself). Go ahead and ask if you can't find them already answered. Most of them probably are, among the millions of questions here.